# Wordpress get_terms argument passing issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing a weird issue with get_terms() function of wordpress.

```
<?php $x=1220;
$terms = get_terms("topics", 'hide_empty=0&parent=$x' );
<ul class="ul1">
<?php foreach ($terms as $term) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'topics'); ?>">
<?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
</li><?php }; ?> </ul>
```

is not returning any terms but when I use the value 1220 directly instead of $x, it is returning values. The following code is working properly.

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("topics", 'hide_empty=0&parent=1220' );
<ul class="ul1">
<?php foreach ($terms as $term) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'topics'); ?>">
<?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
</li><?php }; ?> </ul>
```

I need to use variable as I will be getting term id from elsewhere. Please tell me what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes `'` will print the `$` sign as it is rather of showing the value of the variable

Consider this

```
$a = 9;
echo '$a'; // output = $a
echo "$a"; // output = 9
```

in your case just change

```
$terms = get_terms("topics", 'hide_empty=0&parent=$x' );
```

with double quotes `"`

```
$terms = get_terms("topics", "hide_empty=0&parent=$x" );
```

or just concate the variable with the string with single (or double quotes)

```
$terms = get_terms("topics", 'hide_empty=0&parent=' . $x );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$terms = get_terms("topics", 'hide_empty=0&parent=$x' );
```

with

```
$terms = get_terms("topics", 'hide_empty=0&parent='.$x );
```